# MongoDB Query Not Using Expected Index

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization

I have a query
`{discontinued:0, status:1, visibility:4, "out_of_stock_backend_item.id":{$ne:12524}}`

I'm expecting it to use the index

```
discontinued:-1
status:1
visibility:1
out_of_stock_backend_item.id:1
```

But somehow the above index is coming in the rejected plan and the one in the winning plan is

```
discontinued:-1
status:1
visibility:1
entity_id:1
```

How I can make it use the correct index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/) method, as the documentation said:

> "hint" force MongoDB to use when performing the query. Specify the
> index either by the index name or by the index specification document.

```
db.collection.find().hint( { field: 1 } );
```

OR using the index name

```
db.collection.find().hint( "index_name" )
```